# sed behavior different when put into bash script

Tags: linux, bash, sed, cygwin

I have a bunch of python source files that I am converting to 3.4 syntax.  If I use the following command: `sed -r 's/^print\s(.+$)/print\(\1\)/g' 1.12.py > 1.12a.py`
in Cygwin it will add the required parentheses to the print commands to be syntactically correct for 3.x python.  However when I try to put this into a bash script as:

```
#!/bin/bash

# This is a program to remove "from Tkinter import *" occurances from source code
# and to replace it with "from tkinter import *" so it will work in python 3.3, which
# is what I'm using to program the GUI in

sed -i 's/from\ Tkinter/from\ tkinter/g' *.py

# this line is supposed to add parentheses to all print statements since python 2.7 did not 
# require parentheses around print statements
for pyFiles in *.py
    do
        newPref=${pyFiles%.py}
        #echo $pyFiles
        newName="${newPref}a.py"
        sed -r 's/^print\s(.+$)/print\(\1\)/g' $pyFiles > $newName
    done
```

For some reason this creates the ""a.py version of all the files but it does not add the 
parentheses to the print statements like it does when I just execute the sed command directly.  I am probably missing something obvious.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: could you post content of one such python file. which fails

Comment: This one works fine on my test. since you want to match every `print` drop the anchor `^` at the begining of regex sed -r 's/print\s(.+$)/print\(\1\)/g'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the sed command as

`sed -r 's/print\s(.+$)/print\(\1\)/g' $pyFiles > $newName`

will replace every `print` in the source

- whats wrong in

`sed -r 's/^print\s(.+$)/print\(\1\)/g' $pyFiles > $newName`

`^` anchors the regex at the begining of the string. That is it matches only when the print occures at the begining of the line. Since the python followes indentation, it maynot always begin at the starting of line rather presceded by tab character `\t`

Comment: But for this command $pyFiles is just the name of a file I want to pass into sed.  I tried using the top line you suggested as well, but I'm still not having any luck.  I also tried swapping the echo command for the cat command to pipe into sed.  I have not yet had any success.

Comment: @wishiwasanindian so you want to change the name of file or the content of the file ?

Comment: Well I am trying to take a list of python files: 1.1.py, 1.2.py, 1.3.py, etc.. and pass them into this script, then I wanted to change any lines in all files that say `from Tkinter import *` to `from tkinter import *`, then also change any print commands to add parentheses for python 3.x since 2.7 does not use parentheses.  I am trying to create a new file to hold the changes of all the originals so it would be a collection of files: 1.1a.py, 1.2a.py, 1.3a.py, etc...

Comment: Yes this was exactly the problem.  I shouldn't have had the beginning of line anchor ^ in my regexp....  All I did was remove this as you suggested @nu11p01n73R and it worked as expected.  Thanks a lot for your help.